# Is there a way to store data to a json array without removing the previously stored data in the json array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to implement a way of getting data from an input box and send the data to a json array, i achieved it but the previous data in the array got removed when pushing a new one. I want all the data to store in the json array. How to achieve this in javascript or jquery. Below is what i have tried.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(() => {
    $('#submit').click(() => {
      var objKey = 0;
      var person = [];

      var name = $('#name').val();
      var age = $('#age').val();
      var address = $('#address').val();
      objKey++;
      var obj = {
        'id': objKey,
        'name': name,
        'age': age,
        'address': address
      }

      var hasMatch = false;

      if (name === '' || age === '' || address === '') {
        alert('Fields should not be null');
        return false;
      } else {
        var index = 0;
        if (index < person.length) {
          ++index

          var animal = person[index];

          if (animal.name == obj.name) {
            hasMatch = true;
            alert('oops');
            return false;
          } else {
            person.push(obj);
            buildTable(person)
            console.log(person);
            return false

          }
        } else {
          person.push(obj);
          buildTable(person)
          console.log(person);
          person += person
          return false
        }

      }

    });

    function buildTable(data) {
      var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row =
          `<tr class="record">
             <td>${data[i].id}</td>
             <td>${data[i].name}</td>
             <td>${data[i].age}</td>
             <td>${data[i].address}</td>
             <td><input type="button" title="Click to remove item" value="delete" /></td>
          </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row`enter code here`
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyo, if i understand you right, the problem's your Array:

```
var person = [];
```

gets (re-)initialized every time you click on the submit button.
Therefore your previous data is lost.

Try to change following code:

```
  $(document).ready(() => {
   $('#submit').click(() => {
    var objKey = 0;
    var person = [];
```

to:

```
  $(document).ready(() => {
   var person = [];
   $('#submit').click(() => {
    var objKey = 0;
```

By declaring person in the ready Block, your Submit-Event has access to this variable.
But doesn't overwrites it everytime you click on the button.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes it helps, but am still having issues. I want it to be like when the delete button in the table is clicked, the element in that index shoulb deleted and the table refetch data from the person array.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're creating a **new** array on each click. Move your `person` variable outside the click handler:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  var person = [];            // <==============
  $('#submit').click(() => {
    var objKey = 0;
```

If you do that, then there's a single array, and `person.push` will add to that array.

Comment: I tried it but still not working, it now gving me errors after the first successful push

Comment: Yes it helps, but am still having issues. I want it to be like when the delete button in the table is clicked, the element in that index shoulb deleted and the table refetch data from the person array. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on click you redefine the array "person" as an empty array. You should define it before in the code.

Comment: I tried it but still not working, it now gving me errors after the first successful push –

Comment: Can you give us details about this errors? What is the scope of this line `person += person `?

Comment: Yes it helps, but am still having issues. I want it to be like when the delete button in the table is clicked, the element in that index shoulb deleted and the table refetch data from the person array. Thanks in advance!!